What purpose does a claiming race serve as compared to just selling a horse to someone without a race?
I read through the Wikipedia description of a claiming race - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claiming_race
I read through a few other write ups also.
But I am unable to figure out why horses are sold this way?
Let's say I own a horse - why would I not sell it in other ways instead of racing it in a claiming race?
I can think of several other ways of selling a horse

I can put up an ad that I want to sell a horse. A buyer comes & negotiates with me & I sell
I have an open auction

etc
So who does a claiming race help? The buyer or the seller or is it someone else?
